# How to pipe multi-line JSON Objects into separate python invocations

Tags: python, json, node.js, stdin, xargs

I know the basics of piping stdin to downstream processes in the shell and as long as each line is treated individually, or as one single input, I can get my pipelines to work.

But when I want to read 4 lines of stdin, do some processing, read 6 more lines, and do the same, my limited of understanding of pipelines becomes an issue.

For example, in the below pipeline, each curl invocation produces an unknown number of lines of output that constitute one JSONObject:

```
cat geocodes.txt \
  | xargs  -I% -n 1 curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='%'&sensor=true' \
  | python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'];"
```

How can I consume exactly one JSONObject per `python` invocation? Note I actually have negligible experience in Python. I actually have more experience with `Node.js` (would it be better to use Node.js to process the JSON curl output?)

Geocodes.txt would be something like:

```
51.5035705555556,-3.15153263888889
51.5035400277778,-3.15153477777778
51.5035285833333,-3.15150258333333
51.5033861111111,-3.15140833333333
51.5034980555556,-3.15146016666667
51.5035285833333,-3.15155505555556
51.5035362222222,-3.15156338888889
51.5035362222222,-3.15156338888889
```

**EDIT**
I have a nasty feeling that the answer is that you need to read line by line and check whether you have a complete object before parsing. Is there a function which will do the hard work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need python or node.js. `jq` is designed specifically for json filtering UNIX style:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Then:

```
cat geocodes.txt  \
  | xargs  -I% curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='%'&sensor=true'  \
  | jq --unbuffered '.results[0].formatted_address'
```

Or, if you want to do this on all your JPG files:

```
find -iname "**jpg" \
  | xargs -n 1 -d'\n' exiftool -q -n -p '$GPSLatitude,$GPSLongitude' 
  | xargs  -I% curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='%'&sensor=true'  
  | jq --unbuffered  '.results[0].formatted_address'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this approach would accomplish what you want. First, save your python script in a file, `my_script.py` for example. Then do the following:

```
cat geocodes.txt \
  | xargs  -I% sh -c "curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='%'&sensor=true' | python my_script.py"
```

Where my_script.py is:

```
import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'];
```

Output:

```
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
```

Seems a bit hacky, I'll admit.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER

I am no bash wizard, so my instinct is to simply do everything in Python. The following script would illustrate that approach in Python 3:

```
import urllib.request as request
import urllib.parse as parse
import json

serviceurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

with open("geocodes.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        url = (serviceurl +
               parse.urlencode({'latlng':line, 'sensor':'true'}))
        with request.urlopen(url) as response:
            bytes_data = response.read()
        obj = json.loads(bytes_data.decode('utf-8'))
        print(obj['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'])
```

Output:

```
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
Cardiff
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I may end up using parts of this even though it goes against my new programming religion (the Unix Philosophy) which says keep your programs small and composable so that you can easily modify them. What I'm trying to do is this: `find -iname "**jpg" | head -10 | xargs exiftool -n -p '$GPSLatitude,$GPSLongitude' | xargs  -I% -n 1 curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='%'&sensor=true' | python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'];"`

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat How about then the Python script simply accepts a some variable number of Lat,Long pairs (i.e. from `xargs exiftool -n -p $GPSLatitude,$GPSLongitude'` and prints to stdout what you want? Is that modular enough? Because I'm not sure how you can work with `curl` and xargs to pipe each JSON object one at a time. Perhaps there's a way.  It certainly seems  unparsimonious to try to parse a garbled mess of JSON objects.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Check out my edit, I believe I've figured out how to accomplish what you want using pipes and the exact  python script you were working with.

Comment: Wow, it really does work. `find -L $PWD -maxdepth 50 -type f -iname "**jpg" | xargs -n 1 -d'\n' exiftool -q -n -p '$GPSLatitude,$GPSLongitude' 2>/dev/null | xargs  -I% sh -c "curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='%'&sensor=true' | python ~/trash/my_script.py" `. The only remaining thing (left to me as an exercise) is to inline the python code so I can just copy and paste this at any host's command line without having to first create a script file. And maybe share it on commandlienfu.com :)

Comment: Ideally I'd like to avoid the subshell with a dynamic string command, but as the any seasoned programmer also knows - get it working first and reap the fruits of using it, and separately try and improve the code's elegance. I should also say, being polite to you payed off. Usually I'd downvote the monolith monster you'd proposed as inferior to the Unix Philosphy. I'm glad I didn't do that. Thank you again :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://trentm.com/json/#FEATURE-Grouping

```
Grouping can be helpful for "one JSON object per line" formats or for things such as:

$ cat *.json | json -g ...
```

To install:

```
sudo npm install -g json
```

I haven't tried this myself so can't verify it works, but it might be that missing link to do what you want (Group JSON)